# Can't understand why foreign keys stay empty with this code

Tags: python, django

I have some code in Django 1.6:

Here are my models.py:

```
class MyClass1
  ... # some stuff

class MyClass2
  ... # some stuff
  fk_to_class1 = models.ForeignKey(MyClass1, blank=True, null=True)
```

And somewhere in a view:

```
list_of_objects2 = []
# list_of_objects1 contains several objects from MyClass1

for elt in list_of_objects1:
  list_of_objects2.append(MyClass2(fk_to_class1=elt))

MyClass2.objects.bulk_create(list_of_objects2)
```

After this, objects from MyClass2 should have the "fk_to_class1" filled with some value, but they're empty.
No errors raised.
I don't understand. Thanks for help.

Comment: Were the objects from MyClass1 _saved_? I'm guessing this will fail if they don't have IDs yet. Also, you're trying to create two copies of the MyClass2 objects, first with .objects.create() and then again with objects.bulk_create().

Comment: are the objects in `list_of_objects1` present in the database ? If not, save it first

Comment: Objects from MyClass1 are saved just before. They have an id in the db. For the two copies, sorry it's a mistake in the code I first wrote, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to "list_of_objects1" which still contains the "elts" without id's.

Maybe you should, kind of "reload" your list after you saved it.

EDIT :
For example, your list looks like that :

```
list_of_objects1 [
    elt1 {id : null}
    elt2 {id : null}
]
```

If you save "list_of_objects1". Your ORM will set the ids in your DB but not in your instance.
So maybe you need to reload your instance from your db with the ids set.

Comment: I used the objects.bulk_create() method to save objects of list_of_objects1 and that was the problem with unset ids. Thx.